# Property Source not getting autowired

Tags: spring-boot

I am using external property sources for some reason one of the external property source is not getting autowired, receiving null pointer while creating the authenticaion bean

### Error Message

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.filechecker.check.Authenticator]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at com.filechecker.check.Authenticator.(Authenticator.java:30) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]

### Line no 30:

```
    String username = emailPropertyConfig.getEmailConfig().getUsername();
```

### not working one

```
@Component
@PropertySource(value="${email.app.properties}",ignoreResourceNotFound = false)
@ConfigurationProperties
public class PropertyEmailConfiguration {

    private EmailConfig emailConfig =  new EmailConfig();

    public EmailConfig getEmailConfig() {
        return emailConfig;
    }

    public void setEmailConfig(EmailConfig emailConfig) {
        this.emailConfig = emailConfig;
    }
}


@Component
public class Authenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator {

    @Autowired
    PropertyEmailConfiguration emailPropertyConfig;

    @Autowired
    CipherCrypt cipherCrypt;

    private PasswordAuthentication authentication;

    public Authenticator() throws InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeySpecException {

        String username = emailPropertyConfig.getEmailConfig().getUsername();
        String password = cipherCrypt.decrypt(emailPropertyConfig.getEmailConfig().getEncryptPassword());
        authentication = new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
    }

    @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return authentication;
    }
}
```

### working one

```
@Component
@PropertySource(value="${external.app.properties}", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
@ConfigurationProperties
public class PropertyConfiguration {

    private List<FileStructureConfig> fileStructureConfig = new ArrayList();

    private List<EmailSendingProperties> emailSendingProperties  = new ArrayList();

    public List<FileStructureConfig> getFileStructureConfig() {
        return fileStructureConfig;
    }

    public void setFileStructureConfig(List<FileStructureConfig> fileStructureConfig) {
        this.fileStructureConfig = fileStructureConfig;
    }

    public List<EmailSendingProperties> getEmailSendingProperties() {
        return emailSendingProperties;
    }

    public void setEmailSendingProperties(List<EmailSendingProperties> emailSendingProperties) {
        this.emailSendingProperties = emailSendingProperties;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access an `@Autowired` property within the constructor. The property cannot be autowired at this stage.
In order for Spring to "bake the bean", Spring has to create your object (using your constructor), and only afterwards it applys the autowiring mechanism to inject `emailPropertyConfig` and `cipherCrypt`. Therefore you cannot access the two `@Autowired` properties within the constructor.

If you need to extract some values from the `emailPropertyConfig` or `cipherCrypt` you can do it in `@PostConstruct`

```
@Component
public class Authenticator {

    @Autowired
    PropertyEmailConfiguration emailPropertyConfig;

    @Autowired
    CipherCrypt cipherCrypt;

    private PasswordAuthentication authentication;

    @PostConstruct
    void init() throws InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeySpecException {

      String username = emailPropertyConfig.getEmailConfig().getUsername();
      String password = cipherCrypt.decrypt(emailPropertyConfig.getEmailConfig().getEncryptPassword());
      authentication = new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
    }

    @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
      return authentication;
    }
}
```

or use constructor injection:

```
@Component
public class Authenticator {

    PropertyEmailConfiguration emailPropertyConfig;

    CipherCrypt cipherCrypt;

    private PasswordAuthentication authentication;

    public Authenticator(PropertyEmailConfiguration emailPropertyConfig, CipherCrypt cipherCrypt) throws InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeySpecException {

      String username = emailPropertyConfig.getEmailConfig().getUsername();
      String password = cipherCrypt.decrypt(emailPropertyConfig.getEmailConfig().getEncryptPassword());
      authentication = new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
    }

    @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
      return authentication;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks i did using the post construct which resolved the issue, apologize i forgot the basics.

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark my answer als "accepted". This way it helps other people to find the correct answer quickly in case they have a similar problem.